# how to use getListView() in Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, listactivity

In ListActivity is can use `this.getListView().addFooterView(footerView);`

but if I use Activity it can't use `this.getListView()`

what should I do?

Answer (score 60):

Whenever you use `Activity` you set `your_layout.xml` as your `Activity`'s `ContentView`. So the `ListView` should b in `your_layout.xml`.

That ListView should have an id attribute defined in xml file say: (`android:id="@+id/list"`).
You get your `ListView` object some thing like this way:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.addFooterView(view);
```

And when you use `ListActivity` you get your `ListView` by calling method

```
ListView list = getListView(); // OR you can do
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);  //consider the android prefix..
```

and please note that while defining any `layout.xml` for `ListActivity` you would have a `ListView` in your layout having id of something like this: `android:id="@android:id/list"`

Comment: Very nice, I like the way you explained both solutions. upvote!

Comment: Where does `view` come from in this line: `list.addFooterView(view);`?

Comment: `view` is the view you want to add to `ListView`'s footer.