# Android_ListView_New activity

Tags: android, android-listview

Can i define a text view and a list view inside a linear layout.

If yes, then i am trying to define a list view and wants every list item to open a new activity. But my activity doesnt run and it shows **"Unfortunately your app is forced to closed"**. Please Please help!

Here is the code:

```
public class Second_listview extends ListActivity
{

static final String[] type = new String[]{

    "Array", "Strings" 

 };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.second_listview);

    // setting up list view

    setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.second_listview, type));
    ListView list = getListView();
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //liking each list item to start a new activity

            switch(arg2)

            {
              case 1 : Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Array_list.class);
                       startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
                       break;
              case 2 : Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), String_list.class);
                       startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
                       break;

            }

        }



    });
}



   }
```

Comment: Please post your logcat error ..

Comment: you are not initializing your list view by findviewby id. log cat please

Comment: unable to add (sry i am a newbie :( )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348544/class-extends-listactivity-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list   use this link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Id of you listview as "@android:id/list" as mentioned below.

```
            <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This may be an issue. if possible let us know your layout file also.

Comment: @chintan khetiya : thnxx for telling. i was doing it wrong. But still it didnt help!

Comment: <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="C++ PROGRAMS" 
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
    
  <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        
  </ListView>
    

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main, type));
```

into

```
setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, type));
```

See the below full Code

```
public class Second_listview extends ListActivity
{

static final String[] type = new String[]{

"Array", "Strings" 

 };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.second_listview);

// setting up list view

setListAdapter (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, type));
ListView list = getListView();
list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //liking each list item to start a new activity

        switch(arg2)

        {
          case 1 : Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(view.getContext(), Array_list.class);
                   startActivityForResult(myIntent1, 0);
                   break;
          case 2 : Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(), String_list.class);
                   startActivityForResult(myIntent2, 0);
                   break;

        }

    }



});
}
}
```

Comment: i changed  it to android.R.id.list but i didnt get android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1?

Answer (score 0):

just do the Following things ...

FirstActivity(MainActivity.java)

```
package com.example.getlistitemvalueinnewactivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import android.widget.ListView;

import android.widget.TextView;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

String[] str={"Hello","Android","Apple","Rakesh","BlackBerry"};

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

  ArrayAdapter arr =new     ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,str);                                                                              

lv.setAdapter(arr);

lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String s= (String) ((TextView) arg1).getText();

//Toast.makeText(this, s, 100).show();

Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.setClass(this, Next.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

bundle.putString("Value", s);

intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

SecondActivity(Next.java)

```
package com.example.getlistitemvalueinnewactivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class Next extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.nextpage);
 TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 String textName_value = bundle.getString("Value"); 
 tv1.setText(textName_value);
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="#000000">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
   </ListView>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

nextpage.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.getlistitemvalueinnewactivity"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Next"></activity>
      </application>

          </manifest>
```