# Set onClickListener to LinearLayout filled by custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I'trying to display two lists inside my ScrollView. I found following solution: [Using a ListAdapter to fill a LinearLayout inside a ScrollView layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405575/using-a-listadapter-to-fill-a-linearlayout-inside-a-scrollview-layout) (filling LinearLayout with custom adapter).

This solution works fine but I don't know how to handle click event on list items. It would be simple if I used ListView (onItemClick method with position parameter) but LinearLayout doesn't support the same functionality.

**My layout:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:background="@color/background_gray_light">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
// here should be view with infobox, not implemented yet //
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/story_list_inbox"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/archive"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_bg"
    android:text="@string/archive"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/story_list_archive"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />     
</LinearLayout>
```

**Populating the lists:**

```
public class StoryListFragment extends Fragment {   
public StoryListFragment() {}

    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_story_list, container,
            false);

    TextView archiveText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.archive);
    archiveText.setText(archiveText.getText().toString().toUpperCase()); 

    final List<Story> storyList = new ArrayList<Story>();
    // filling the list ....

    StoryListAdapter adapter = new StoryListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.story_list_item, storyList);        
    LinearLayout inbox = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.story_list_inbox);

    final int inboxCount = adapter.getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < inboxCount; i++) {
      View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
      inbox.addView(item);
    }   

    /* archive */   
    // filling the list ....    

    LinearLayout archive = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.story_list_archive);

    final int archiveCount = adapter.getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < archiveCount; i++) {
      View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
      archive.addView(item);
    }           

    return view;
}
}
```

**Question:**

How should I make the LinearLayout list items clickable to be able to get the index of the clicked item?

**What I even want to achieve:**

Maybe I'm not even using the right solution, what I'm trying to achieve here is to create something like a message inbox, which consists of two lists - one for newest messages and the second one for the archived messages. I also want to display some content on the top of the lists, so I put it all inside a ScrollView. It should look like this:

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < inboxCount; i++) {
    final int index = i;

    View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
    item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Clicked " + index);
            startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), StoryIntroActivity.class));
        }
    });
    inbox.addView(item);
}
```

Comment: It would be much better if you showed the code.

Comment: you're right, I've added it to my question

Comment: Why not use a `ListView`?

Comment: Because the activity contains more views than just one ListView. It's described in my question.

Comment: But You can use ListView as one of multiple Views in layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set the onClickListener to dynamically created view like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < inboxCount; i++) {
        final int index = i;

        View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
        item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Clicked " + index);
                startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), StoryIntroActivity.class));
            }
        });
        inbox.addView(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*How should I make the LinearLayout list items clickable to be able to get the index of the clicked item?*

You can do as following in order to pass the clicked item's index to another activity where you might want to respond to the click.Inside your `onCreate` do something like this :

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long   id)
{
//position is the item number in your listview
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),xyz.class);
intent.putExtra("itemNo.", position);
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Please note that if your class extends `ListActivity` then only you can use `this.getListView()` directly as above. If you extend `Activity` then refer [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275559/how-to-use-getlistview-in-activity).

**The answer suggests :**

Whenever you use Activity you set your_layout.xml as your Activity's ContentView. So the ListView should b in your_layout.xml.

That ListView should have an id attribute defined in xml file say: (android:id="@+id/list"). You get your ListView object some thing like this way:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.addFooterView(view);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't found your answer helpful. I don't use any ListView in my code.