# How/where in the code to detect wether in ListFragment's ListView all items are visible?

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I am trying to change the ActionBar's action depending on wether all list items are visible (there's less items that fit to the screen => show "Add item" action | there are some items invisible => show "Search" action)

What method of ListFragment should I override in order to be able to use getListView().getLastVisiblePosition() and get not -1?

This is the code from my ListFragment, but in onCreateOptionsMenu lv.getLastVisiblePosition() always returns -1.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list, menu);

    final MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
    final MenuItem add = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_add_item);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    if (lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0 && lv.getLastVisiblePosition() == mAdapter.getCount()-1) {
        // all items visible: show add, hide search
        search.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
    } else {
        // not all items visible: show search, hide add
        add.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: try `Looper.myQueue().addIdleHandler` and call `getLastVisiblePosition` inside `IdleHandler`

Comment: @pskink, I tried adding it in onActivityCreated, and it works, BUT: if I return true, it is being called all the time again and again even when nothing changed or moved, and if I return false it only works once

Comment: you want it to be called once, dont you? if not, return 'false' and `addIdleHandler` each time your adapter size changes

Comment: @pskink that worked, I added it to my adapter's notifyDataSetChanged. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getLastVisiblePosition` returns valid position only when adapter's items were added and layed out by a hosing `ListView`, i don't know any method of asking a `ListView` when it happens, so the best option would be just to listen when the UI thread goes to block waiting for more messages:

> Looper.myQueue().addIdleHandler

and call `getLastVisiblePosition()` inside `IdleHandler#queueIdle()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173369/how-to-check-if-a-my-listview-has-scrollable-number-of-items can be also useful

Answer (score 1):

To get visible child count in `ListView`.

```
int visibleChildCount = (listView.getLastVisiblePosition() - listView.getFirstVisiblePosition()) + 1;
```

Now get total child count in `ListView`,

```
int totalChildCount = listView.getAdapter().getCount;
```

Hide / Show Actionbar Icon.

```
if(totalChildCount>visibleChildCount){
  // Visible
}else{
  // Gone
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: no unfortunately I already know this, and it's even in the code in my question. My problem is what method of the ListFragment could I override in order to get the real results in getLastVisiblePosition(), because anywhere I tried (except the onclick of the list items, just to verify the calculation is correct) I get -1 because the list is not populated yet